# how to access the first preceding text node using jdom2

Tags: java, dom, tree, implementation

Given an element node, I want to access the first preceding text node using jdom2. For example:

```
<tr>
   <td>Price:</td>
   <td>
       <span>
           <b>$15.99</b>
       </span>
       <span>
           ........
       </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

if we given element ,how do we get the preceding text "Price:"?

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I have the answer. The XPath:

```
"preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][position()=1]"
```

can find the preceding text node.